# What does the cursor hint message System_CAPS_protmethod mean?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, schema, msdn

While researching MSDN documentation I ran into the following cursor hint.  Can anyone tell me what the hint represents.  I tried finding the answer to this question myself, to no avail.  There are others, as well such as `System_CAPS_protproperty`, `System_CAPS_pubmethod`, and `System_CAPS_pubproperty`.

As a programmer I know part of the answer is: public and protected; method and property... but what does the rest mean?

[image]